# Performance Monitor: Memory\Page Faults/sec vs Process\Page Faults/sec

Tags: performance, memory, process, performance-monitoring

When I was investigating some Hard Page Faults I came across this. Objects Memory & Process give different value's from the same counter: Page Faults/Sec. Are there some OS related processes that cause page faults that aren't monitored by the Performance Monitor object Process? Why are Process\Page Faults/sec always below Memory Page Faults/sec?

[Screenshot Performance Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltZSH.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The counter `Memory => Page Faults/sec` represents a system-wide count of page faults. Both soft and hard faults. Both user mode and kernel mode.

On the other hand, the counter `Process => Page Faults/sec` is a set of counters that has an instance for every user mode process that is running on the machine. So you can inspect page faults incurred by one specific process. Or you can select the `_Total` instance to get a sum of all page faults incurred by all running processes.

But even if you selected `_Total`, you could still only get page faults incurred by user mode processes. Not page faults in the kernel, for example by device drivers.

Page faults can be satisfied at CPU IRQL 0 (all user mode and most kernel mode,) or 1 (kernel APC and page faults,) but page faults can not be satisfied at IRQL 2 (dispatch) or above.

Page faults come in two flavors: soft faults and hard faults. Hard faults are the ones that can cause serious performance degradation because you have to go to disk (swap file) to satisfy a hard fault. Soft faults are not so bad because the page is still in RAM somewhere, it's just not in the process' working set and has to be retrieved from elsewhere in main memory which is much faster than going to disk.

So `Process => Page Faults/sec => _Total` is a sum of all the page faults incurred by all the running user mode processes. `Memory => Page Faults/sec` is that *plus* any additional kernel mode page faults.